# Can we scanf an array?

Tags: arrays, c, integer, scanf, sizeof

I want to input an array of integers then print out the even numbers from the inputted numbers..

```
example is if I input 2466688992,
it will output 24666882;
```

I have a my code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a[5],i;
printf("Enter array of numbers: ");
scanf("%d",&a);

for(i=0; i<sizeof(a); i++){
if(a[i]%2==0)
printf("%d",a[i]);  
}
   getch();
   return 0;
   
}
```

It resulted into garbage : 2468000075416640419940000004225568000

Comment: `2466688992` is larger than a 32-bit `int` can hold using format specifier `%d`. You could use `unsigned` and `%u`. If you actually want an array with those digits in it, input to a string. `char s[32]; scanf("%s", s);`

Comment: how to input into a string and then test each index of string if even or not

Comment: You can do a loop, I see, so loop over each character of the string, which contains (probably) the ASCII value for each digit. But not to `sizeof(a)`, but `strlen(a)`. The `sizeof` operator does not give you the number of elements (used) in an array. It tells you the number of bytes storage used by the object.

Comment: I tried this                                                                                                                               #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
char a[5],i;
printf("Enter array of numbers: ");
scanf("%s",&a);

for(i=0; i<strlen(a); i++){
if(a[i]%2==0)
printf("%s",a[i]); 
}
   getch();
   return 0;
   
}

Comment: That is not what I wrote. `char a[5]` can hold 4 digits and the null terminator.

Comment: do you know what the code is weather?

Comment: it stopped working

Comment: There is enough information already in the comments I think, but I would use `scanf("%31s", s);` instead.

Comment: Your example only has one "number".  You are talking about _digits_.

Comment: See my answer for both numbers and digits

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should scan the array as a string (unless you want to impose the number of items in the array), and then parse the string to store the different numbers:

```
long a[50];
char buf[1024];
printf("Enter array of numbers: ");
scanf("%s",buf);
int len = strlen(buf);
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; ) {
    long sign = 1;
    long n = 0;
    if (buf[i] == '+') {
        ++i;
    }
    else if (buf[i] == '-') {
        sign = -1;
        ++i;
    }
    if (isdigit(buf[i])) {
        while (isdigit(buf[i])) {
            n = 10 * n + buf[i++] - '0';
        }
        a[j] = n * sign;
    }
    else
        i++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
   if (!(a[i] ℅ 2)) // true if even
      printf("%ld ", a[i]);
```

This will store all your digits in your array `a` of size `j`.

Edit: if you are talking about digits then its easier:

```c
char buf[1024];
printf("Enter array of numbers: ");

scanf("%s",buf);
int len = strlen(buf);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   if (isdigit(buf[i]) && !((buf[i] - '0') ℅ 2)) // true if even, note that '0' equals 0x30 so there is no need to sub it to check for odd/even in reality.
      printf("%c ", buf[i]);
```

Comment: C:\installationxampp\htdocs\c\even2.c [Error] expected ':' before ')' token in the !((buf[i] + '0') ℅ 2)) part

Comment: This is correct but can you explain in simple terms the !((buf[i] - '0') ℅ 2))?

Comment: you don't need to do - '0', it worked when I deleted it

Comment: ! Is equivalent to == 0, so the remainder of division by 2 is 0

Comment: Yes you dont need the - '0' as I said in my comment, but this is due to the fact that digits char value have the same remainder than their digit value

Comment: (buf[i]) % 2) means remainer so example is (2%2)=(0) so, !(0)=not zero, is that what it ment? so it validates if its not zero?

Comment: (buf[i] % 2)  extends to (buf[i] % 2 != 0)  and (!(buf[i] % 2))  extends to (buf[i] % 2 == 0)

Comment: actually it worked when I just did isdigit(buf[i]) && buf[i] % 2==0

Comment: would you accept if its isdigit(buf[i]) && buf[i] % 2==0?

Comment: it works because '0' is equivalent to 48 as ascii value, so its valid, but this is not the digit value, but the char value

Comment: no worries anyways I hope you understand that buf[i] is 48 if '0' and 49 if '1', so you are lucky that the odd/even will be respected. as we checked that it is a digit, there is no need to substract 0... Its more about readability

Comment: why does character value matter? like if 0=48 and 1=49?

Comment: buf[i] is a character representing the digit, hence its value is not 0 to 9 but 48 to 57 (0x30 to 0x39) which luckily follows the same odd/even pattern

Comment: If you say -'0' to 0x30 to get if its even how about how to remove the x

Comment: 0x is for the hexadecimal representation of a number, 48 is base 10 and 30 is based 16

Comment: so the character that our code has is base 10 right?

Comment: neither, a character is base 2, represented on 8 bits, at the computer level, it does not understand base 10 or 16. Only a stream of bytes made of 8 bits. 48 = 0x30 = 0b110000 that is what the computer truly sees

Comment: value of 48-0, 49-1, 50-2, ... 57-9, that is why we got even because 48,50 .. 56 is even right?

Comment: exactly you understood well!

Answer (score 1):

This is the function that prints even numbers in an integer :

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main(){

               int num,rem,even=0,digit;

               printf("  Enter an integer number: ");

               scanf("%d",&num);

               printf("\n  The even digits present in %d are \n",num);

               while(num>0){

               digit = num % 10;

               num = num / 10;

               rem = digit % 2;

               if(rem == 0)
               even++;
               printf("\n  %d.",digit);

               }

        return 0; 

    }
```

Comment: can we not do : input-2577889, output-288, can we not write the input in a single line?

Comment: Yes we can, I just understood so I edited my answer !

Comment: its not the odd, its the even

Comment: It is right but can we output in left to right even numbers?

Comment: The message text says “Odd”; the code prints even numbers.